# jmeter-no of threads and loop controller

Tags: jmeter

I am running JMeter with number of threads=10,60,140 for the multiple thread groups and We are getting high response time.

If we changed recording controller to loop controller and same values given in loop count, then we are getting least response time.

Why there is a difference between them? Which response should we consider?

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: Actually,we are getting high response time for the loop count=60 when compared to loop count=140.

Answer (score 1):

Threads are executed in parallel while loop is executed samplers sequentially.

Executing numerous calls in parallel on same machine versus sequentially is basically creating more stress on server (more hits per seconds).

When server is under stress there may appears waits/locks because of reaching max number of `X`, where `X` can be either database/server/resource/...

Therefore your response time will be higher when using threads over loop number.

Instead of this approaches, you probably should consider try to simulate real users behavior, see for more details an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274647/jmeter-and-simulating-the-real-users).